# improvement of program through inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, code-duplication

I have written a program that reads in from a file and store the information in my own made collection class. My program works fine however i was wondering if there is anything i could do to improve my program and prevent duplicate code through inheritance and other Java features. Here are my classes. I have added comments to explain what each class does.

```
abstract class Order { //superclass
 private int quantity; //instance variables

 public Order(int quantity) { //constructor
  this.quantity = quantity;
}

 public int getQuantity() { // instance method
  return quantity;
}

 public abstract double totalPrice();

 public String toString() {
  return "quantity: " + quantity;
}

} //super Class Order

class Coffee extends Order { //subclass 
 private String size; //instance variables

 public Coffee (int quantity, String size) { //constructor
  super(quantity);
  this.size = size;
}

 public double totalPrice() { //instance method to calculate price for the item
  double priceSmall = 1.39;
  double priceMed = 1.69;
  double priceLar = 1.99;
  double total = 0;

  if (size.equals("small")) { 
   total = priceSmall * getQuantity();
  } else {
   if (size.equals("medium")) {
    total = priceMed * getQuantity();
  } else {
    if(size.equals("large")) {
      total = priceLar * getQuantity();
    }
  }
}
  return total;
} //totalPrice


public String toString() {
 return "Coffee ("+ size + "): " + super.toString() ;
}

} //coffee sub-class

class Donuts extends Order { //sub-class
 private double price; //instance variables
 private String flavour;

public Donuts(int quantity, double price, String flavour) { //constructor
 super(quantity);
 this.price = price;
 this.flavour = flavour;
}


public double totalPrice() { //instance method to calculate price
 double total = 0;
 int quantity = getQuantity();

 if(quantity < 6) {
   total = (price * quantity);
   double tax = 0.07 * total;
   total += tax;
 } else {
   total = price * quantity;
 }
 return total;
} //totalPrice

public String toString() {
 return "Donuts("+ flavour + "): " + super.toString() + ", price: " + price;
}

} //class Donuts

 class Sandwich extends Order { //Sub-class
  private double price; // instance variables
  private String filling;
  private String bread;

 // constructor
  public Sandwich (int quantity, double price, String filling, String bread)   {
   super(quantity);
   this.price = price;
  this.filling = filling;
  this.bread = bread;
 }

  public double totalPrice() { //instance method
   double total = 0;
   int quantity = getQuantity();

   total = (price * quantity);
   double tax = 0.07 * total;
   total += tax;

   return total;
  } //totalPrice


  public String toString() {
   return "Sandwich ("+ filling + ") ( " + bread + "): "+ super.toString() + 
  ", price: " + price ;
 }

} // Sandwich class

  class Pop extends Order { //sub-class
   private String size;
   private String brand;

   public Pop(int quantity, String size, String brand) { //constructor
    super(quantity);
    this.size = size;
    this.brand = brand;
   }

   public double totalPrice() { //instance method
    double priceSmall = 1.79;
    double priceMed = 2.09;
    double priceLar = 2.49;
    double total = 0;

  if (size.equals("small")) { 
    total = priceSmall * getQuantity();
 } else {
  if (size.equals("medium")) {
    total = priceMed * getQuantity();
  } else {
    if(size.equals("large")) {
      total = priceLar * getQuantity();
    }
  }
}
 return total;
} //totalPrice

 public String toString() {
  return "Pop ("+ brand + ") (" + size + "): " + super.toString() ;
 }
} // class Pop
```

There are four products namely Coffee, donuts, sandwiches and pops whose orders i am storing and then printing their total price.

**A sample of the file i am reading is this:**

> Coffee,3,medium
>
> Donut,7,0.89,chocolate
>
> Pop,5,large,Splat! Cola
>
> Sandwich,1,3.89,mystery meat,37-grain whole wheat

My program is a tad long but i am hoping if SO community could help me improve my program. What i am looking to improve is, that i have `totalPrice()` method which i am overriding in each class. But if you look closely `coffee` class and `pop` class are somewhat similar in their attributes. Same goes for `donut` class and `sandwiches` class. Is there any-way i can prevent the duplication of the code in those classes?
I hope everything is self-explanatory if there is explanation needed i am willing to provide that.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is sometimes over-used in OO systems.  Generally composition is a better technique - read up on "inheritance vs. composition".

For this case specifically, it's odd and probably not helpful that you are trying to treat an inventory item in the store as an order.  An order has items associated with it, but the items not really an order in and of itself.

In that regard you could have a class, StoreItem, that has a name and a price.  You could also allow that class to have an optional size property that affects the price.  So for an store item you can call item.getName() and item.getPrice().  When you construct a store item you could initialize it either with just the namd and price, or with a name, size and a price for those items that have sizes.

Then you can just have a Store class, and the store has an inventory of items - a list of available items.  An order is made for a list of items, and your cost calculation could happen once in the order class.  It just loops through its list of items and asks each its price.

With this solution you'd end up with Item, Store, Order, and a main program somewhere, but to extend your problem to include more items you don't need to add any new classes at all.

Comment: Judging by your answer you are sort of implying that i don't have any MAJOR code duplication? I got what you are saying about the `StoreItem` class though.

Comment: Well no the duplication isn't so much an issue as extensibility - to add items with your solution you need to add classes.  You do have duplication with regards to how size affects price with this solution, though, that could be eliminated by just having a single StoreItem class.

Answer (score 0):

Though your program is also fine and also their can be multiple solution to your questions based on specifications.

First thing you specified you wanted to avoid duplication, i see duplication particularly in method totalPrice() which can cause problem if you have to add some changes to it, you will be affecting all classes. Changes like you want to add 1% discount in total price for example. Considering this i suggest changes as below:

```
//add utility interface which can be used by all Concrete product classes
interface PriceCalculator {

    static double totalPrice(Map<String, Double> priceMap,String size, int quantity) throws Exception{
        Double rate=priceMap.get(size);
        if(rate==null){
            throw new Exception("something really bad happened.Missing price");
        }

        return (rate * quantity);
    }

}

class Coffee extends Order  { //subclass 
    private String size; //instance variables
    private Map<String, Double> priceMap=new HashMap<>();

    public Coffee (int quantity, String size) { //constructor
        super(quantity);
        this.size = size;
        priceMap.put("priceSmall", 1.39);
        priceMap.put("priceMed", 1.69);
        priceMap.put("priceLar", 1.39);
    }

    @Override
    public double totalPrice() { //instance method to calculate price for the item
        try {
            return PriceCalculator.totalPrice(priceMap, size, getQuantity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    } //totalPrice


    public String toString() {
        return "Coffee ("+ size + "): " + super.toString() ;
    }

} //coffee sub-class
```

Another specification if asked is to make pricing not hard coded.You can do that by using Properties class to load key-value pair of size-price from external file.